# Least Common Multiple & Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: number-theory

> Let set 
>   $$
> S = \{s\space |\space s=\frac{lcm(a,\space a+d,\space a+2d,\space ...,\space a+10d)}{a+10d}\}$$
>
> Where $a,\space d$ are positive integers, and $lcm$ is the least common multiple function.
>
> What is the smallest element in $S$?

(The work I've done so far)

If $\gcd(a,\space a+d,\space\dots,a+10d)=g>1$, 
there must be another case: $a'=a/g,\space d'=d/g$.

So  we can assume $\gcd(a,\space a+d,\space\dots,a+10d)=1$.

And the smallest one I found is $s=2310$, when $a=2,\space d=1$.

Since $2310=2\times3\times5\times7\times11$,

I'd guess the problem is somehow related to prime factorization, but still don't know how to prove it.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Can you solve a simpler problem, like ${\rm lcm}(a,a+d)/(a+d)$ or ${\rm lcm}(a,a+d,a+2d)/(a+2d)$? Where does this problem come from, please?

Comment: I designed a program that generates cases for all $a+10d<100000$, 
and the smallest one so far is $s=2310(a=2,d=1)$.

Comment: Note that $2310$ is the product of the primes 2, 3, 5, 7, 11. Note also that you haven't answered either of my questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson

The first one is quite obvious. 
Let $a=1$, then for any d, the formula gives $1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson

The second one is a bit harder. 

Let $\frac{1}{x_1}=\frac{a+2d}{lcm}$, 
$\frac{1}{x_2}=\frac{a+d}{lcm}$, 
$\frac{1}{x_3}=\frac{a}{lcm}$.

Clearly $\{\frac{1}{x_1},\frac{1}{x_2},\frac{1}{x_3}\}$ is A.P.

Notice that $x_3 > x_2 > x_1 \geq 1$, and the goal is to find the min $x_1$.

If $x_1=1$, it isn't hard to find out that no such $x_2$ can fit.

And for $x_1=2$, we can have $x_2=3,\space x_3=6$.

So the min is 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson

The problem is from CHKMO 2006 #19, and I read the official answer.

It also gave 2310, but the prove was wrong.

Comment: Good. What is CHKMO?

Comment: @GerryMyerson "Hong Kong (China) Mathematical Olympiad"

Answer (score 0):

$s=\dfrac{a(a+d)(a+2d)...(a+10d)}{\gcd\{a,(a+d),...,(a+10d)\}(a+10d)}=\dfrac{a(a+d)(a+2d)...(a+9d)}{\gcd\{a,(a+d),...,(a+10d)\}}$

Clearly the A.P. is increasing, so if we consider $D$ to be the $\gcd$ for brevity, we must have $D\leq a$.

Since we are looking for the smallest $s$ it suffices to consider $D=a$.

Now $D|(a+d)\implies a|d\implies d=at$ for some integer $t$.

Then $s=\dfrac{a(a+at)(a+2at)...(a+9at)}{a}=a^9(1+t)(1+2t)...(1+9t)$

Now we want to make $a$ as small as possible. Consider $a=1$ first (and $D=1$ trivially) which gives $s=(1+t)(1+2t)...(1+9t)$. To make this even smaller, consider $t=1$
. Then $s=2.3.4.\dots.10=10!$.

This is the smallest $s$.

Comment: Does $lcm\{a,a+d,\dots,a+10d\}\times\gcd\{a,a+d,\dots,a+10d\}=a(a+d)\dots(a+10d)?$

Comment: No, that equation only works for pairs of numbers, ${\rm lcm}(a,b)\gcd(a,b)=ab$. Doesn't work for triples, quadruples, ..., 11-tuples. You shouldn't have much trouble finding a counterexample.

Comment: You are very correct. Sorry, I was way too fast!